# Entity Framework Core 2.0 migrations update database with seed data throwing error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.0 code first migration. I am trying to run the migration sin to the new database. I am using seed data. I am getting error if i use seed data and no error if i comment out the seed data method. Not sure what is the problem. Can anyone please help?

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'WorkflowBranches' in the database.

The tables are created, but no records appear in the `migrationhistory` table, even though I have around 5 migration scripts. Also the seed data is inserted.

> I think the database is getting created twice. I am using migrations
>   script and also in the seed method, there is
>   dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync(). This could be the reason but
>   i am not sure.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Other code
    services.AddTransient<DbSeeder>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env,
                      DbSeeder dbSeeder)
{
    app.UseMvc();

    dbSeeder.SeedAsync(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
}
```

DbSeeder.cs:

```
using Workflow.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Workflow.DBContext
{
    public class DbSeeder
    {
        readonly ILogger _Logger;

        public DbSeeder(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("DbSeederLogger");
        }

        public async Task SeedAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            //Based on EF team's example at https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs
            using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<WorkflowDBContext>();
                if (await dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync())
                {
                    if (!await dbContext.Alert.AnyAsync())
                    {
                        await InsertAlertsSampleData(dbContext);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task InsertAlertsSampleData(WorkflowDBContext dbContext)
        {
            //Insert Risktypes
            var riskTypes = GetRiskTypes();
            dbContext.RiskType.AddRange(riskTypes);

            try
            {
                int numAffected = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                _Logger.LogInformation($@"Saved {numAffected} riskTypes");
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                _Logger.LogError($"Error in {nameof(DbSeeder)}: " + exp.Message);
                throw;
            }

            //Insert categories
            var categories = GetCategories(riskTypes);
            dbContext.Category.AddRange(categories);

            try
            {
                int numAffected = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                _Logger.LogInformation($"Saved {numAffected} categories");
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                _Logger.LogError($"Error in {nameof(DbSeeder)}: " + exp.Message);
                throw;
            }

            //var alerts = GetAlerts(categories);
        }

        private List<Alert> GetAlerts(List<Category> categories)
        {
            return new List<Alert>();
        }

        private List<RiskType> GetRiskTypes()
        {
            var riskTypes = new List<RiskType>
            {
                new RiskType { Name = "Risk1"},
                new RiskType { Name = "Risk2"}
            };

            return riskTypes;
        }

        private List<Category> GetCategories(List<RiskType> riskTypes)
        {
            var categoryList = new List<Category>();

            var categories = new string[]
            {
                "Category1Risk1",
                "Category2Risk1",
                "Category3Risk1",
                "Category1Risk2"
            };

            //Low Risk
            foreach (var category in categories.Take(3))
            {
                categoryList.Add(new Category
                {
                    Name = category,
                    RiskType = riskTypes.FirstOrDefault(rt=>rt.Name=='Risk1')
                });
            }

            //High Risk
            foreach (var category in categories.Skip(3))
            {
                categoryList.Add(new Category
                {
                    Name = category,
                    RiskType = riskTypes.FirstOrDefault(rt=>rt.Name=='Risk2')
                });
            }

            return categoryList;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: reference answer in other post

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Ef Core 2.0 you need to kwno this:

> In 2.0 projects using EF Core 2.0, Program.BuildWebHost is invoked to
>   obtain the application services. Unlike 1.x, this has the additional
>   side effect of invoking Startup.Configure. If your 1.x app invoked
>   database initialization code in its Configure method, unexpected
>   problems can occur. For example, if the database doesn't yet exist,
>   the seeding code runs before the EF Core Migrations command execution.
>   This problem causes a dotnet ef migrations list command to fail if the
>   database doesn't yet exist. Consider the following 1.x seed
>   initialization code in the Configure method of Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
```

> In 2.0 projects, move the SeedData.Initialize call to the Main method of Program.cs:+

```
var host = BuildWebHost(args);

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        // Requires using RazorPagesMovie.Models;
        SeedData.Initialize(services);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
    }
}

host.Run();
```

> As of 2.0, it's bad practice to do anything in BuildWebHost except
>   build and configure the web host. Anything that is about running the
>   application should be handled outside of BuildWebHost — typically in
>   the Main method of Program.cs.

Today i changed my code for this code, and mi solution worked properly.

I am leaving you the reference link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#move-database-initialization-code